# A bottom border line till the end of the div, even if the text does not continue

Tags: html, css

I am making a small 'news' tab for my website, i however want to have a border line until the end of the div, even if this means it goes past the text i have put, this would happen for every news line, currently i have tried this

```
.news {
width: 50%;
height: 40%;
background-color: #FFF;
float: right;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-right: 60px;
}

.news a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-size: 21px;
}

.news p a {
content: "";
padding-bottom: 1%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.news image {
/* Nothing */
}
```

the border-bottom that i have defined should go until the end of the div but i haven't been able to find away to accomplish this, so i was wondering if this was possible to do or not

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
header {
  margin-top: 2%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 180px;
}
header p {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  padding-top: 4.5%;
}
#nav {
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#content {
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 73.9%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.news {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
.news a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 21px;
}
.news p a {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.news image {
  /* I am not sure what to do here just yet */
}
#form {
  padding-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
#form label {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
}
#form input {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#form input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
#form input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  outline: none;
}
#form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #006099;
  border: 1px solid #006099;
}
#form input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: #005099;
  outline: none;
}
#form label p {
  color: #11FF00;
}
.downloadable {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.downloadable a {} .downloadable a img {
  width: 40%;
}
.downloadable a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF9900;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.1%;
}
#nav #right {
  float: right;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #FFFF0F;
}
#login {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#login form {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p>Lost Story</p>
  </header>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn'])) { echo "<li><a href=\"register.php\ ">Register</a></li>"; } ?>
      <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="forums.php">Forums</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="vote.php">Vote</a>
      </li>
      <div id="right">
        <?php if(isset($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn']) && !empty($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn'])) { echo "<li><a href=\"php/logout.php\ ">Log Out</a></li>"; } else { echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\ ">Log in</a></li>"; } ?>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="news">
      <p><a href="location-to-news.php">This is a test</a>
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Website made by Lucas Ouwens</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is a good idea to include a link to JSFiddle or something to visually show your problem.

Comment: Please supply the HTML so that we can get some idea of how this looks.

Comment: @markbernard I have now added this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `border-bottom` does not go till the end as the `a` element to which you apply it has `inline` display (default `display`) and takes the width of the content.

Add `display: block` to `.news p a` and it will extend to the whole width.

Cheers!

Snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
header {
  margin-top: 2%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 180px;
}
header p {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  padding-top: 4.5%;
}
#nav {
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#content {
  margin-left: 12.1%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 73.9%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.news {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
.news a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 21px;
}
.news p a {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  display: block;
}
.news image {
  /* I am not sure what to do here just yet */
}
#form {
  padding-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
#form label {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
}
#form input {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#form input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
#form input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  outline: none;
}
#form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #006099;
  border: 1px solid #006099;
}
#form input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: #005099;
  outline: none;
}
#form label p {
  color: #11FF00;
}
.downloadable {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.downloadable a {} .downloadable a img {
  width: 40%;
}
.downloadable a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF9900;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.1%;
}
#nav #right {
  float: right;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #FFFF0F;
}
#login {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#login form {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p>Lost Story</p>
  </header>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn'])) { echo "<li><a href=\"register.php\ ">Register</a></li>"; } ?>
      <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="forums.php">Forums</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="vote.php">Vote</a>
      </li>
      <div id="right">
        <?php if(isset($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn']) && !empty($_COOKIE[ 'LoggedIn'])) { echo "<li><a href=\"php/logout.php\ ">Log Out</a></li>"; } else { echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\ ">Log in</a></li>"; } ?>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="news">
      <p><a href="location-to-news.php">This is a test</a>
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Website made by Lucas Ouwens</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.news p a` section to be this instead:

```
.news p a {
   content: "";
   padding-bottom: 1%;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Inline elements like `<a>` will only be as wide as their contents. By changing your `<a>` to `display: block;`, you can then change its width to your liking. In this case, I believe you want `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use **hr** tag for it and style it? See below (line in red), this line:

```
<hr style="border-top: 2px solid; background-color: #ff0000; color:#ff0000">
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 1px;
 min-height: 1px;
 }

html,body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 115%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
 }



header {
 margin-top: 2%;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 180px;
}

header p {
 font-size: 64px;
 margin-left: 40%;
 padding-top: 4.5%;
}

#nav {
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#nav ul li a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 11px 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 }
 
#content {
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 73.9%;
 background-color: #FF0000;
}

.news {
 width: 50%;
 height: 40%;
 background-color: #FFF;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-right: 60px;
}

.news a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 21px;
}

.news p a {
 content: "";
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.news image {
 /* I am not sure what to do here just yet */
}


#form {
 padding-top: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 
}

#form label {
 font-size: 25px;
 border: none;
 }

#form input {
 width: 30%;
 height: 30px; 
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#form input[type=text], input[type=password] {
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 2%;
}

#form input[type=text], input[type=password] {
 outline: none;
}

#form input[type=submit] {
 background-color: #006099;
 border: 1px solid #006099;
}

#form input[type=submit]:focus {
 background-color: #005099;
 outline: none;
}

#form label p {
 color: #11FF00;
}

.downloadable {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 80px;

}

.downloadable a {

}

.downloadable a img {
 width: 40%;
}

.downloadable a img:hover {
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);

}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FF9900;
 width: 75%;
 margin-left: 12.1%;
}

#nav #right {
 float: right;
}

#nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 
}

#nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
 transition: 0.5s;
 background-color: #FFFF0F;
}

#login {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 width: 25%;
 height: 20%;
 border: 1px solid #444444;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#login form {
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header><p> Lost Story </p></header>
    <div id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['LoggedIn'])) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"register.php\">Register</a></li>";
    }
    ?>
    <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="forums.php">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="vote.php">Vote</a></li>
     <div id="right">
     <?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_COOKIE['LoggedIn'])) {
      echo "<li><a href=\"php/logout.php\">Log Out</a></li>";
      } else {
       echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\">Log in</a></li>";
      }
     ?>
     </div>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <div class="news">
                <p>
                    <a href="location-to-news.php">This is a test</a>
                    <hr style="border-top: 2px solid; background-color: #ff0000; color: #ff0000">
                </p>
   </div>
  </div>
   <footer> Website made by Lucas Ouwens </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```